# How to post inside a loop with AngularJS 1.4.8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops

I have found other answers to similar questions of mine, but none of them worked for me.

I'm trying to create a cards game. Here I'm trying to shuffle through the cards and give each player 5 random Money cards ( $scope.MoneyCards ). Instead, this code gives all the 15 cards to the last player on the loop.

The results with ( Angular 1.0.8 ) is exactly how I want it. But when I'm using any later version this doesn't work. I'm working on migrating to 1.4.8 .

This is the code I'm using:

```
    $scope.StartGame = function() {
    $http.get('/api/MoneyCards')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.MoneyCards = data;
            console.log(data);

            // Loop through players
            player = 1;
            while(player < 4) {
            // Loop through money cards to give each player 5 cards
            i=0;
            while(i < 5) {
                // Shuffle
                var Mfloor = Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.MoneyCards.length);
                $scope.randomCard = $scope.MoneyCards.splice(Mfloor, 1 );
                // Create the card in the Deck table and attach it to a player
                $scope.createDecks($scope.randomCard[0],player,0);
                i++;
            }
            player++;
        }

        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

This is the `createDecks` function

```
$scope.createDecks = function(card, player, type) {

    $scope.formData.player = player;
    $scope.formData.type = type;
    $scope.formData.card = card;

    $http.post('/api/Decks', $scope.formData)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.formData = {};
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

I'll try to adopt this to JSFiddle.

Code provided by [georgeawg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33850533/929844) using $q and still not working

```
    $scope.StartGame = function() {
    $http.get('/api/MoneyCards')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.MoneyCards = data;
            console.log(data);

            var player = 0;
            while(player < 3){
            var i = 0;
            var qPromise = $q.when(0);
                while(i < 5) {
                    // Shuffle
                    var Mfloor = Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.MoneyCards.length);
                    var randomCard = $scope.MoneyCards.splice(Mfloor, 1 );
                    // Create the card in the Deck table and attach it to a player

                    qPromise = qPromise.then( function (response) {
                        return $q.all([
                            response,
                            $scope.createDecksPromise(randomCard[0],player,0)
                            ]);
                        });
                    i++;
                };
                player += 1;
            };

            qPromise.then ( function(response) {
                      //do whatever
                    console.log(response);
                 }) .catch ( function (error) {
                      throw error;
                 });

        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

Comment: You should use the angular service `$q` for this. You can read up about how it works here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: `Promises.push($scope.createDecks($scope.keyword[0],player,0));` ( Inside the loop )
`$q.all(Promises);` ( outside the loop ) and still not working - what am I doing wrong? BTW the loop is still running the code inside the loop instead of just pushing it to the promises array.

Comment: Move `var qPromise = $q.when(0);` above `var player = 0;`. You are initializing it in your inner loop so it only works on the last player.

Comment: I moved it. It's still gives it to the last player on the loop :( all assigned to player 3

Comment: I found the answer thanks. @georgeawg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the answer, here is the code:

```
$scope.StartGame = function() {
    $http.get('/api/MoneyCards')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.MoneyCards = data;
            console.log(data);

            var qPromise = [];
            var player = 1;
            while(player < 4){
            var i = 0;
                while(i < 5) {

                    qPromise.push([
                        Mfloor = Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.MoneyCards.length),
                        randomCard = $scope.MoneyCards.splice(Mfloor, 1 ),
                        $scope.createDecksPromise(randomCard[0],player,0)
                    ]);

                    i++;
                };
                player += 1;
            };
            return $q.all(qPromise);

        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

Thanks to [georgeawg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33850533/929844), the $http.post `$scope.createDeckPromise()` should return promises:

```
$scope.createDecksPromise = function(card, player, type) {

    var formData = {};
    formData.player = player;
    formData.type = type;
    formData.card = card;

    return $http.post('/api/Decks', formData);
};
```

For whoever is having the same issue. This is the solution without my code:

```
$scope.RunCode(){
    var Promises = [];
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 5){
        Promises.push($http.post('/api/whatever', formData));
        // to add multiple functions to the promise use [], example: Promises.push([doThing1, doThing2]); 
        i++;
    };
    return $q.all(Promises);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First your`createDecks` function should **return** promises.

```
$scope.createDecksPromise = function(card, player, type) {

    var formData = {};
    formData.player = player;
    formData.type = type;
    formData.card = card;

    return $http.post('/api/Decks', formData);
};
```

Your iterative loop should then **chain** those promises.

```
var i = 0;
var qPromise = $q.when([]);
while(i < 5) {
    // Shuffle
    var Mfloor = Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.MoneyCards.length);
    var randomCard = $scope.MoneyCards.splice(Mfloor, 1 );
    // Create the card in the Deck table and attach it to a player
    // Add closure for randomCard and player 
    (function (randomCard, player) {
        qPromise = qPromise.then( function (response) {
            response.push(
                $scope.createDecksPromise(randomCard[0],player,0)
            );
            return $q.all(response);  
        });
    })(randomCard, player); 
    i++;
};

qPromise.then ( function(response) {
          //do whatever
     }) .catch ( function (error) {
          throw error;
     });
```

Remember that when chaining promises you should always **return** something to the `.then` method.

Also be aware that the `.then` method has a different response structure than the `.success` method.

The AngularJS team has come to their senses and deprecated `.success`. We should all be using the `.then` method now. To learn more about the deprecation (or should I say failure) of `.success` and `.error`, see the latest [AngularJS $http API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

To learn more about `$q.when`, look at the [AngularJS $q Service API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have replaced my code with the one you provided. I put your loop inside the players loop to check if it is working and it still gives all the cards to the last player.

Comment: I edited to add closure for randomCard and player variables.